# How do I retrieve all children from one parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have problem which I can't seem to find solution to. I have two classes with a one to many relationship.

UserEntity is the parent class - this class has two parents for the one child. The class is also a self referencing class.

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "user")
  @Component
  public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Basic(optional = false)
      @Column(name = "user_id")
      private Integer id;

      @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
      @JoinColumn(name="checker_id")
      private UserEntity checker;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy="checker", orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private Set<UserEntity> setters = new HashSet<UserEntity>();

      @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="setter")
      private Set<Module> sModule = new HashSet<Module>();

      @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="checker")
      private Set<Module> cModule = new HashSet<Module>();
```

So within the class is one to many relationship with the Checker as the parent to Setters as children. In turn, both Checker and Setter are parents to the Module class. A setter will be responsible for setting a module while the checker will check that it is correct. So both are associated with the same module.

Module

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "modules")
 @Component
 public class Module implements Serializable{

         @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
         @JoinColumn(name="user_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
         private UserEntity setter;

         @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
         @JoinColumn(name="checker_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
         private UserEntity checker; 
         ///getters and setters
```

So with each user I want to list the modules associated with them. So in the setter section the modules will be shown on their specific page, while in the checker section the corresponding modules will also be listed.

I have tried to do this by getting a user by the id and automatically getting the modules. In this case the parent is the setter (I'm using the setsModule). But the method is returning null.

```
    @Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public UserEntity getWithModules(Integer id){

    //Retrieve User
    Criteria crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(UserEntity.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    UserEntity userEntity = get(crit);

    //Retrieve the modules for the setter
    crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Module.class);

    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));

    crit.addOrder(Order.asc("moduleId"));
    Set<Module> sModule = new LinkedHashSet<Module>(crit.list());
    userEntity.setsModule(sModule);  

    return userEntity;
}
```

The DAO criteria code for the method above

```
    public T get(Criteria criteria) {
    return (T)criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Am I going about this the right way or do I have to set it up differently? I would liek some insight on what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a criteria query to get an entity by ID. There's a method for that: `Session.get()`. And since you have an association between your entities, there's no reason to use a query to get this association either.

If I understand correctly, all you need is:

```
UserEntity userEntity = (UserEntity) session.get(UserEntity.class, id);
```

And the to get the setter modules, you simply need to call

```
userEntity.getSModules();
```

And to get the checker modules, you simply need to call

```
userEntity.getCModules();
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion. I have created a method for getting the user by the id and returning the user using - userEntity.getsModule. Requesting the user with the modules results in the error - Required Integer parameter 'userId' is not present